# hibernate - delete element in mysql from selected list

Tags: java, hibernate

I have small issue

I want to delete element in db (mysql), which is in selected list:

```
    List<PsProductAttribute> psProductAttributes = sessionShop.getNamedQuery(PsProductAttribute.GetByProductId)
                                .setInteger("idProduct", psProduct.getIdProduct())
                                .list();


                        for (PsProductAttribute psProductAttribute : psProductAttributes) {
...

                            sessionShop.getNamedQuery(PsProductAttribute.DeleteByAttributeId)
                                    .setParameter("idProduct", psProductAttribute.getIdProduct())
                                    .executeUpdate();

                        }
```

After this i get:

```
    ERROR: org.springframework.scheduling.support.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler - Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
org.hibernate.StaleStateException: Batch update returned unexpected row count from update [0]; actual row count: 0; expected: 1
```

I understand that i want to delete element, which is in previously selected List.

But how to delete element ?

Comment: What does the `PsProductAttribute.DeleteByAttributeId` query look like?

Comment: it's @NamedQuery @NamedQuery(name = PsProductAttribute.DeleteByAttributeId, query = "Delete from PsProductAttribute where idProduct = :idProduct")

Comment: In a delete scenario you usually only get that exception when you try to delete an an entity that doesn't exist. Any chance some other process is deleting it first?